# How to create a private wireless network off of public wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/679281/how-to-create-private-mixed-wired-wireless-network-connected-to-shared-wifi), but that was never answered. Mine is different enough that I believe it warrants a new question.

I am an organizer for an event coming up and we have some unique networking needs. During the event, all of our administrators require internet access. This internet access is provided by public wifi (for example, in the event hall) or by 3G wifi hotspot devices. We would like run a private wireless network off of a personal router that has a printer and hard drive but that is also connected to the internet. Configuration would look like this:

```
Public/hotspot wifi
    |
  (???)
    |
Router (ASUS RT-N65U) -- Printer & Hard drive
    |
 Users Connected to Private Wireless network
```

One possibility is to use a computer to connect to the public wifi, and then bridge this connection to an ethernet output connected to the router. However, if I understand correctly, this computer would not be able to access the printer and shared hard drive because it is plugged into the "internet in" port on the router.

What is the best way to set a network like this up?

Something that may be relevant, there is no DD-WRT firmware available for the given router, but there is [another option](https://code.google.com/p/rt-n56u/) for 3rd party firmware.

Comment: Watch out, the IP you pick up off public wifi probably has a limited pipe or bandwidth restrictions.  Double NAT isn't near the problem anymore that it used to be.  If you are renting an event space ask about internet options. One event I was at, we brought down the entire hotel's internet, at another they planned on not providing internet and leaving it up to everyone to bring there own cell carrier connection--the meeting room was below street level and 3 carriers had zero bars (and no one thought of checking that in advance).

Comment: @Tyson the Bandwidth requirements are pretty low for our event.