# Secure Public Wifi at Apartment with Personal Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security, wireless-router

I recently moved into an apartment and wifi is included in the rent; however, it is a public network for each building and is not secure. I currently own a router but I do not know how to use it to redirect the public wifi signal.

So, is there a way for me to capture the signal with one device, transmit it via an Ethernet cable to my router, and then broadcast a secure version that I can safely use?

Also, I don't have much experience with this so don't assume that I know something that may be obvious. It's likely that I don't. I found a similar question to this:

[How to create a private wireless network off of public wifi?](https://superuser.com/questions/788427/how-to-create-a-private-wireless-network-off-of-public-wifi)

but the question was never answered.

Feel free to let me know if you need more info before you can answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: No; You won't because the traffic to the router and the public WiFi will still be insecure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work – some Wi-Fi APs can work in client (station) mode, although I've seen it more often in dedicated APs ("range extenders") than in combo "wireless routers". Though OpenWRT should allow it in a wi-fi router as well. (I've once used a spare laptop this way.)

Though, as mentioned in comments, this will only give you a private LAN, but *not* a private connection to the Internet. Your neighbours will still be able to see which websites you browse.

(One way to avoid that would be by setting up a VPN connection on the router, although obviously that needs a VPN server elsewhere...)

Comment: My main concern isn't that my neighbors can see what websites I visit, in fact, I don't care if they can. However, will I be able to visit those websites in a secure fashion? As in, would they still be able to grab personal information? Also, you said you used a spare laptop to do this. So, could I use a laptop to connect to the public wifi, then use my ethernet cable and connect the laptop to my router to rebroadcast the signal?

Comment: @user6535839 - As long as you are connecting to the websites with SSL, you'll be fine.

Comment: @user: That *doesn't depend* on whether you get your own router or not – the apartment's open Wi-Fi **remains the weakest link**, revealing all that is not encrypted at a higher layer. HTTPS (and SSL/TLS) will always remain private; but regular HTTP will never be, nor will DNS.