# Create private network from public wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, subnet, private-network

My question is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/788427/how-to-create-a-private-wireless-network-off-of-public-wifi), which was never answered. I live in an old apartment building that is not wired for internet access, and therefore pay a monthly fee to access an XFINITY® WiFi by Comcast hotspot, a signal for which I can connect to from my room. I would like to create a private WiFi network in my apartment using the XFINITY hotspot as an internet source. On the face of it, this seems like it should be relatively easy to do. Yet I am unable to find a solution on the internet. (The term "subnet" comes up a lot, but I don't know how to create one of these.) Is there a particular WiFi router that I can buy that would allow me to do this in a relatively painless manner? My ideal solution would look like this:

Internet -->

XFINITY WiFi Hotspot -->

My Router -->

My Private Wifi Network -->

My Devices (e.g., Amazon Echo, Chromecast, Roku, XBox, laptops, iPad, Philips Hue, etc.)

Comment: Windows 10 has the ability to create a Virtual Router. Third-party applications provided that ability before it was added to Windows.  A Wi-FI extender would be less technology challenging then using an actual router.

Comment: From my understanding, wouldn't I need a wired Ethernet connection to plug into the Windows 10 machine? And then I would be able to share that via WiFi to other devices? The trouble is, I do not have wired Ethernet access to the XFINITY hotspot. I can only access it via WiFi.

Comment: No;  If you have 2 wireless adapters you can connect to the hotspot with one then use the other to create a virtual router that other devices use to connect to your pc.  My original comment seems pretty clear i understood your restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible solutions I can think of:

1. Windows 10 laptop acts as a router.

This is relatively simple to set up: connect to the XfinityWifi hotspot from a laptop (or desktop, doesn't really matter) and enable the Mobile Hotspot option found in Settings.

[image: Image shows mobile hotspot configuration page in Windows 10]

2. DD-WRT in client mode

Basically in this mode the router connects wirelessly to the XfinityWifi hotspot and broadcasts a signal. I'm not really well versed on how to set this up, but I can point you to [this article on "Client Mode" on the DD-WRT wiki](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode) and [this article on connecting/broadcasting more than one Wi-Fi network at a time](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Multiple_WLANs).

In the past I have tried using Wi-Fi extenders (for example, something like [this](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/WN1000RP.aspx)) but they just connect the computers directly through to the XfinityWifi hotspot and doesn't create a network. This might be what you're looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

You want a wireless bridge device (sometimes also called a client bridge). This acts as a wireless client which "collects" the WiFi signal and outputs it over a wired Ethernet connection. You can then plug that Ethernet cable into a regular home router just like you would any wired Internet connection.

Wireless bridges are available for pretty low cost from many network equipment vendors. If you're more adventurous you could turn another old router into a wireless bridge using firmware like OpenWRT or LEDE or you coul accomplish the same thing with a Raspberry Pi. Specific instructions for how to do that though is really a separate question.

Comment: Another solution is to use a computer, like Raspberry Pi for example, to create a client / AP. The upside is that you can do "other stuff" with it too (web server, iptables, etc). The downside is that it will probably be a lot more complicated to set up, unless you're familiar with Linux networking.